1930s romantic comedy about girl & aspiring musician
I need help with the name of a movie. This movie is from the 1920-1930's. It is black and white. I can't remember the famous actors, but for their time, they were famous (I recall looking it up). Here is what I remember:
A man is having a coffee (possible at a train station or a coffee house) in a major city. This man is a famous/aspiring pianist/violinist. He meets a male friend and a female acquaintance. The female and musician hit it off (comedy and romance), but he has to leave because he has concerts to fulfill. Their discussion really focuses around her story (well educated). I think they basically agree that they will never see one another again, but somehow they end up crossing paths again. (I can't recall if she is married or estranged or never married).
At some point in the movie, they are in a cocktail lounge and have a spat. In another scene, he is in his huge, fancy loft looking out large picture windows and talking to that male friend from before. A coffee table has some large magazines on it and a grand piano is there. He basically talks about all the pressures he is under and how it is getting harder to focus because he loves her. He is considering abandoning his musical career.
That is all I remember. Does anyone know the name of this movie?

I'm assuming this is American?  also, when/how did you watch it?  do you remember what the actors looked like?

Was it a musical too?

Are you sure about the decade? Going strictly by hunch here, but this sounds more like a 40s\50s melodrama.
